# How show that label content is loading?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uilabel

for my app I need to load some content from my webservice. I want to display it within a simple `UILabel`. This works fine so far.

But since the request is asynchronous the process might take some time.

Now I want to indicate the loading process with a little image like you see in the picture.

Is that a  buildin-feature in xcode4 somewhere in the interface-builder?
Is it possible to assign an image to a UILabel and how do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) which can be told to start and stop animating. You can eve say to hide when it stops animating so you can bind this view to the logic of showing your label.